# Python error when calling NumPy from class method with map

Tags: python, numpy

The following code throws me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 25, in <module>
    sol = anna.main()
  File "", line 17, in main
    sol = list(map(self.eat, self.mice))
  File "", line 12, in eat
    calc = np.sqrt((food ** 5))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
#import time

class anaconda():

    def __init__(self):
        self.mice = range(10000)

    def eat(self, food):
        calc = np.sqrt((food ** 5))
        return calc

    def main(self):

        sol = list(map(self.eat, self.mice))
        return sol


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #start = time.time()
    anna = anaconda()
    sol = anna.main()
    print(len(sol))
    #print(time.time() - start)
```

I believe I made a serious mistake, because it seems like Python interprets the 'np' from NumPy as an integer, but I have no glimpse why that is.

Comment: In a Python shell, what is the result of `import numpy as np`, `np` and `type(np)`?

Comment: You get         :>>> np
<module 'numpy' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>
>>> type(np)
<class 'module'>
>>>

Comment: Restart your kernel.

Comment: I got the same error. When I modify `self.mice = range(10000)` to `self.mice = range(1000)` then the error disappears.

Comment: @coldspeed: I already tried on two different computers

Comment: @Flabetvibes To be more precise, it works with `7132` but fails with `7133`. It must have to do with some memory/cache management. That's a very interesting issue.

Comment: @Flabetvibes True, same for me. But it makes absolutely no sense??

Comment: @DeepSpace In fact `np.sqrt(7132 ** 5)` doesn't work for me but `np.sqrt(7131 ** 5)` works.

Comment: Not an answer, but using lists and `map` and range objects and other non-NumPy data structures and control flow with NumPy is usually a bad idea; among other problems, it'll usually be vastly slower than a solution based on NumPy whole-array operations, as well as taking more memory and not handling variable-dimensionality inputs well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll try to add a precise answer to those that have already been given. `numpy.sqrt` has some limitations that `math.sqrt` doesn't have.

```
import math
import numpy  # version 1.13.3

print(math.sqrt(2 ** 64 - 1))
print(numpy.sqrt(2 ** 64 - 1))

print(math.sqrt(2 ** 64))
print(numpy.sqrt(2 ** 64))
```

returns (with Python 3.5) :

```
4294967296.0
4294967296.0
4294967296.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(numpy.sqrt(2 ** 64))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

In fact, `2 ** 64` is equal to `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` and, according to the standard of C data types (version C99), the `long long unsigned integer` type contains at least the range between `0` and `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` included.

The `AttributeError` occurs because `numpy`, seeing a type that it doesn't know how to handle (after conversion to C data type), defaults to calling the `sqrt` method on the object (but that doesn't exist). If we use floats instead of integers then everything will work using `numpy`:

```
import numpy  # version 1.13.3

print(numpy.sqrt(float(2 ** 64)))
```

returns:

```
4294967296.0
```

So instead of replacing `numpy.sqrt` by `math.sqrt`, you can alternatively replace `calc = np.sqrt(food ** 5)` by `calc = np.sqrt(float(food ** 5))` in your code.

I hope this error will make more sense to you now.

Comment: absolutely! Thank you very much for the explanation. I absolutely didn't took into concern that it might be related to the integer data type returned by range(). Basically your's is the best answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree, the link between this AttributeError and the integer data type isn't obvious.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noticed, this boils down to the fact that `np.sqrt(7131 ** 5)` works but `np.sqrt(7132 ** 5)` returns an error:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.sqrt(7131 ** 5))
print(np.sqrt(7132 ** 5))

# 4294138928.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(np.sqrt(7132 ** 5))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

Since [`np.sqrt` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html) don't mention any bounds on the argument,  I'd consider this a numpy bug.

Comment: True so far, but notably from my terminal I can:                                                 >>> print(np.square(80000**5))
10737418240000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @Ma Tze `np.square` is different from `np.sqrt`.

Comment: oh typo, sry to everyone. Its absolutely true, @DeepSpace is right

Answer (score 1):

You can replace numpy by the built in function math.sqrt like this:

```
import math  

class anaconda():

    def __init__(self):
        self.mice = range(10000)

    def eat(self, food):
        calc = math.sqrt(food ** 5)
        return calc

    def main(self):

        sol = list(map(self.eat, self.mice))
        return sol


if __name__ == '__main__':
    anna = anaconda()
    sol = anna.main()
    print(len(sol))
```

I think that the problem of your code is that you are probably reaching a limit (not sure yet why it raises that confusing error) because 10000**5 is a reeeally big number.
You can check this out by reducing your range(10000) to range(1000). You will notice that your code runs perfectly fine then:

```
import numpy as np  

class anaconda():

    def __init__(self):
        self.mice = range(1000)

    def eat(self, food):
        calc = np.sqrt((food ** 5))
        return calc

    def main(self):

        sol = list(map(self.eat, self.mice))
        print sol
        return sol


if __name__ == '__main__':
    anna = anaconda()
    sol = anna.main()
    print(len(sol))
```

This runs perfectly fine, just by reducing range(10000) to range(1000)

Comment: True, useful option. But the error doesn't make sense, still?

Comment: Exactly... I have no clue why that error gets raised. The error should say something related to sqrt being applied on a number bigger than what it can deal with.

Comment: Please notice what I just edited in my answer. If you reduce range(10000) to range(1000) your code runs perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

## Plain Python

Actually, you need neither `numpy` nor `math` because [`sqrt(x)` is `x**0.5`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537383/why-is-x-frac12-the-same-as-sqrt-x). So:

```
sqrt(x**5) = x ** (5/2) = x ** 2.5
```

It means you could replace your code with:

```
class anaconda():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mice = range(10000)

    def eat(self, food):
        calc = food ** 2.5
        return calc

    def main(self):
        sol = list(map(self.eat, self.mice))
        return sol


if __name__ == '__main__':
    anna = anaconda()
    sol = anna.main()
    print(len(sol))
```

## NumPy

If you want to use NumPy, you can enjoy the fact that you can work with arrays as if they were scalars:

```
import numpy as np

class anaconda():

    def __init__(self):
        self.mice = np.arange(10000)

    def eat(self, food):
        return food ** 2.5

    def main(self):
        return self.eat(self.mice)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    anna = anaconda()
    sol = anna.main()
    print(len(sol))
```

## Short refactor

Removing all the unneeded object-oriented-with-weird-names, your code becomes:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.arange(10000) ** 2.5)
```

Comment: Thats another good idea, using pure python. Actually, the names are not for fun, but it"s a boiled down version of a way more complex script using multiprocessing, I used this one to find some errors when it came up with this one.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be your exact case, but if you want to take the square root of a large number AND you want to have control of the precision of the result, going either to `math.sqrt()` or `x ** 0.5` would not be much useful because your result will end up being a float number, and for large enough inputs, this will hit the limitations of float numbers.

One possibility for the specific case of `sqrt` is to look into an integer-only implementation of the square root algorithm, e.g. [`flyingcircus.util.isqrt()`](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/flyingcircus/src/cabfbaad57b33d8b65643904b55045b670181064/flyingcircus/util.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) (Disclaimer: I am the main author of [`flyingcircus`](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus/)).

Alternatively, for a more general solution, one may look into [`gmpy`](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy) (or any other arbitrary precision library with Python bindings).